# Excel function in access db

Tags: excel, ms-access, excel-formula, ms-access-data-macro

How to use excel function in access db?
We have a policy numbers I would like to know if the policy number repeats return 0 otherwise 1

In excel: =IF(A2=A1),1,0

How can I write this formula in access?

Please appreciate your help.

Thanks.

Comment: In `MS-Access` already have `IIf ( expr , truepart , falsepart)`. [Article link](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/iif-function-32436ecf-c629-48a3-9900-647539c764e3)

Answer (score 1):

In Access VBA you would use a *Boolean* (True/False)

```
Match = (Value2 = Value1)
```

If you insist, that Match must be an *Integer*, this will do:

```
Match = Abs(Value2 = Value1)
```

In a query it would be like:

```
Match: Abs([Field2]=[Field1])
```